# No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'andr oid:textColor

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-preferences

I get this error:

> Error:(2118, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'andr         oid:textColor'.

On this line in the file values.xml:

```
<item name="andr         oid:textColor">@color/menu_section_header</item>
```

(note the spaces after "andr")

The file is app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml

I just added this dependency to the app build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:24.2.1'
```

Also in there are:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0' compile
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
```

This existing solutions to this error involve conflicting SDKs (e.g. compiled SDK version is 23 and support library is 24). This does not appear to be the case here.

Project Structure settings:

> The following SDKs installed:
>   Android 7.0 (Nougat)            24  2   Installed
>   Android 6.0 (Marshmallow)       23  3   Installed
>   Android 5.1 (Lollipop)          22  2   Installed
>   Android 5.0 (Lollipop)        21    2   Installed
>   Android 4.4W (KitKat Wear)  20  2   Installed
>   Android 4.4 (KitKat)            19  4   Installed

```
Compile SDK Verson: API 24: Android 7.0 (Nougat)     
Min Sdk Version: API 19: Android 4.4 (KitKat)       
Target SDK Verson: API 24: Android 7.0 (Nougat)
```

What am I missing?

Edit:

I've found the problem thanks to @BlackBelt and @LahruiPinto.

What I didn't understand about the build process is that apparently all values from all files in the "res/values" are put into a intermediate file called "values.xml". In my file res/values/styles.xml, I had a CR/LF after "item name="andr" which presented itself as spaces in the values.xml file. I'm not sure why it didn't flag the error in the styles.xml file. After fixing the styles.xml, the project built correctly.

Comment: Why do you have  the spaces after "andr"? Did you tried after removing those space?

Comment: I didn't put them there. When I delete them, they just reappear. This file appears to be an accumulation of all values. Ones that  I have defined and 'system' values.

Comment: *When I delete them, they just reappear.*, then you are probably editing the wrong file. One of the generated files from AS

Comment: All the files "values.xml" in the directories of this project are under that intermediate directory.

Comment: Found the solution (add to original quesiton). Not sure why all the hate. It's a confusing error message due to the values.xml vs style.xml issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error because of the space in the below line.

change

```
<item name="andr         oid:textColor">@color/menu_section_header</item>
```

to

```
<item name="android:textColor">@color/menu_section_header</item>
```

Comment: See my comment above about this.

Comment: at what moment it just reappear? in rebuild?

Comment: Yes, as you can see by the path of the file that I put in the question, it is an intermediate file of the build.